# Check which Button is active in Wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-7

I have a `ListView`. This is the `populateItem`-Method:

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Test> test) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test t = test.getModelObject();
    IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink link = new IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink("categoryMenuItemLink", t)
    test.add(link)
}
```

Which generates a `HTML` like this:

```
<a>Test 1</a>
<a>Test 2</a>
```

For my Application I need to keep track which of the `links` is active.
So my first Thought was implemeting my own `IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink`, something like this:

```
public class MyLink extends IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink<String> {

private boolean isActive;

public CategoryAjaxLink(String id) {
    super(id);
    this.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

}

@Override
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    this.isActive = true;
    // Load images into different panel...
}
```

But now the problem is that if I click both `links` then both will be set to active.
Another approach was to use the `AttributeModifier` but again it failed, since I can only declare that the Link is active by CSS.
What I want to accomplish? Theses `links` will update another panel which loads a lot of images. And the first `link` is always active so the images will load by default. By clicking the second `link` the second Link will become active and it starts loading different images.

However how can I keep the state of which `link` is active or not when the links are created over `populateItem`?

Answer (score 2):

you could create a custom link class that uses a common Model instance to keep track of the active link:

```
public class MyLink extends IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink<String>
private final IModel<String> activeLink;    

public CategoryAjaxLink(String id, IModel<String> activeLink) {
    super(id);
    this.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    this.activeLink = activeLink;
}

@Override
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    activeLink.setObject(getId());
    // Load images into different panel...
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return getId().equals(activeLink.getObject());
}
```

As I said to make this work you have to use the same model instance for each link.